# Using Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse show that there is no set of first order formulas

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Using Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse show that there is no set of first order formulas.
We consider class of all graphs (finite and finite). We would like to show that it is not possible to axiomatize in first logic that:  *nodes may be coloured with finite number of colors in such way that each triple has different colors.*

I can show it using compactness theorem, but I must use Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse game.  I know that we should show that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there are exists two graphs such that one of them satisfy this sentence and second not satisfy and, whats vitally, duplicator always may win in game with $n$ stages.

Comment: What is a triple? Also, be careful what you write: "show that there is no set of first order formulas" is nonsense, of course. There are lots of sets of first order formulas!

Comment: triple it is triangular (1-2-3-1)

Comment: So you mean three vertices, such that each pair is connected by an edge? In graph theory, such a configuration is called a "triangle" or a "$K_3$" (complete graph on $3$ vertices).

Comment: Yes, indeed  $K_3$

Comment: It's much easier to prove this using compactness than using EF games. Why do you want a proof using EF games?

Comment: To practise this technique